# Log out clear session in node.js?

Tags: node.js

When doing log out in node.js, do we just `delete session.user` . Is there a need to manually clear `req.locals.var` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.locals` only exists for the lifetime of a single HTTP request, so there's no need to manually clear it in terms of any subsequent requests. Normally the response to a logout request is a redirect which won't need anything from `req.locals`, but if for some reason your app does look at that during the actual logout request itself, it won't do any harm to clear it out with `req.locals = {};`.